# Plotting Voigt Function in Python

Tags: python, scipy, integration

I've been trying to plot the following function in Python:

$H(a,u) = \frac{a}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{exp(-y^2)}{a^2 + (u - y)^2}dy $

But I keep receiving the following error:

```
File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 383, in _quad
return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

error: Supplied function does not return a valid float.
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 0.1
pi = np.pi
u = np.linspace(-100,100,200)


def integrand(a,u,y):
    top = np.exp(-y**2)
    bottom = a**2 + (u - y)**2
    return top/bottom

def func(u):
    res = np.zeros_like(u)
    for i,val in enumerate(u):
        y,err = integrate.quad(integrand, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(a,u))
        res[i] = y
    return (a/pi)*res


plt.plot(u,func(u))
```

u is a series of values which represent a range of frequencies. I've always struggled to get integration to work in python. Is there a good direction anyone could recommend me to go in to get it to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen the documentation of `scipy.integrate.quad`? I see at least two issues with your code:

- the first argument in the definition of `integrand` should be the integration variable `y`.
- the argument `u` in `integrand` is a scalar, yet you are providing a vector in the `args` option of `integrate.quad`.

If all you want to do is plot your function, the following snippet is compact and clean

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Voigt(a, u):
    I = integrate.quad(lambda y: np.exp(-y**2)/(a**2 + (u - y)**2),-np.inf, np.inf)[0]

    return (a/np.pi)*I

a = 0.1
u_range = np.linspace(-100,100,200)

plt.plot(u_range, [Voigt(a, u) for u in u_range])
```

[image]

Comment: I hadn't actually. I had been on the documentation for scipy.integrate but never thought of going to the quad part. Foolish on my behalf. Thanks for this. I never knew that you could put a for loop inside of a plot function!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mostly correct. Just change `u` to `val` when you call `integrate.quad`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 0.1
pi = np.pi
u = np.linspace(-100,100,200)


def integrand(a,u,y):
    top = np.exp(-y**2)
    bottom = a**2 + (u - y)**2
    return top/bottom

def func(u):
    res = np.zeros_like(u)
    for i,val in enumerate(u):
        y,err = integrate.quad(integrand, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(a,val))
        res[i] = y
    return (a/pi)*res

plt.plot(u,func(u))
```

As mentioned by @Stelios, passing `u` (an array) to `integrand` means it will return an array, while `integrate.quad` expects a scalar. Here, we just use the fact that you already run over every `val` of the array with  `enumerate`.